# JS сохранить select в localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сохранить выбранное значение из `select`'a в `localStorage` и после перезагрузки страницы `option` из `selecta` оставался бы выбранным?

С кнопками `radio` смог такое реализовать, а вот с `select`, не получается.

Вот мой код:

```js
function SetData (elem) { 
    localStorage.setItem(elem.getAttribute('name'), elem.getAttribute('id'));

} 
function GetData (item) { 
    return localStorage.getItem(item); 
}

/**
 * следующий код выполняется после загрузки страницы.
 */
window.onload = function() {
    /**
     * узнаем, какое значение у нас в localStorage.getItem(item)
     */
    var Item = GetData ('type');

    /**
     * если значение установлено (!undefined)
     */
    if(Item != undefined) {
        document.getElementById(Item).checked = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="green" id='GreenCheck' onchange="SetData(this);"> Зеленый <br> 
<input type="radio" name="type" value="blue" id='BlueCheck' onchange="SetData(this);"> Синий <br> 
<input type="radio" name="type" value="red" id='RedCheck' onchange="SetData(this);"> Красный <br>

<select onchange="SetData(this);">
  <option name="type" id="GreenCheck" value="green" onchange="SetData(this);">Зеленый</option>
  <option name="type" id="BlueCheck" value="blue"onchange="SetData(this);">blue</option>
  <option name="type" id="RedCheck" value="red" onchange="SetData(this);">red</option>
</select>
```

Так же код в редакторе:
https://jsfiddle.net/synapse3/tvc5u948/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<select name="selectcheck" onchange="SaveSelectValue(this)">
  <option value="green">Зеленый</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
  <option value="red">red</option>
</select>

function SaveSelectValue(el) {
  localStorage.setItem(el.name, el.value);
}
function LoadSelectValue(el) {
  return localStorage.getItem(el.name);
}

let selectCheck = document.querySelector("[name='selectcheck']");
selectCheck.value = LoadSelectValue(selectCheck);
```

Comment: но после перезагрузки стр, option - не показывается

Comment: не видно выбранного значения

Comment: @TileaWebsite Пропустил `return` в `LoadSelectValue`.

Comment: супер, то что нужно, сейчас попробую привязать в своему конвертеру валюты, надеюсь сработает